# Searching HTML table gives incorrect results

Tags: javascript, html

I have problem with searching my in HTML table.

The code used to work properly, but after I added an expandable row in it, it doesn't work anymore. Ex. After adding a row, I search for a value that is not on the table, and this search gives me the value of the last row.

How can I solve this? I really need the expandable row of my table, so I can't remove it.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function doSearch() {
            var searchText = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value;
            var targetTable = document.getElementById('report');
            var targetTableColCount;

            //Loop through table rows
            for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < targetTable.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
                var rowData = '';

                //Get column count from header row
                if (rowIndex == 0) {
                    targetTableColCount = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.length;
                    continue; //do not execute further code for header row.
                }

                //Process data rows. (rowIndex >= 1)
                for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < targetTableColCount; colIndex++) {
                    var cellText = '';

                    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
                        cellText = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(colIndex).innerText;
                    else
                        cellText = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(colIndex).textContent;

                    rowData += cellText;
                }

                // Make search case insensitive.
                rowData = rowData.toLowerCase();
                searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();

                //If search term is not found in row data
                //then hide the row, else show
                if (rowData.indexOf(searchText) == -1)
                    targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'none';
                else
                    targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).style.display = 'table-row';
            }
        }
    </script>
```

And here is the HTML code:

```
<table id="report" class="table table-bordered ">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                        <th>Track Number</th>
                        <th>Document Title</th>
                        <th>Document Type</th>
                        <th>Date Filled</th>
                        <th> </th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                    <?php while ($row1 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)): ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row1['tracknum'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row1['doctitle'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row1['doctype'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row1['datefilled'] ?></td>
                                 <td>
                                 <div class="arrow"><a id="menu-toggle" href="#" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i></a></div>
                                 </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td colspan="5">
                            List of Signatories
                            <ul style="list-style-type:circle">

                            <?php 
                            require_once 'dbconfig.php';
                            try {
                            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",
                                $username, $password);

                            $_tempp1 = $row1['tracknum'];
                            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT statement ");
                            $stmt->bindParam(1, $_tempp1, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30); 
                            $stmt->execute();
                            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                                ?>
                            <?php 
                                echo "<li>" . $row['signatoryname'] . "</li>";
                            }
                            } catch (PDOException $pe) {
                            die("Error occurred:" . $pe->getMessage());
                    }
                            ?>
                            <button type="button" class="btnviewpdf btn btn-xs btn-warning"  >
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>View
                            </button>

                            </ul>  
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                    </table>
```

This is the sample code https://jsfiddle.net/q17cz0o1/

Comment: it doesnt work properly. it doesnt give the desired output. its working perfectly before i ADDED an expandable row, but when i added an expandable row. it doesnt give the desired output.

Comment: Why a proper question always has to be milked? What is the desired output? Please explain your problem in details. We're not going to guess, what you want your code to do, and what it does instead. You know, you explain.

Comment: why is it that when i added an expandable row the search is not working properly anymore sir. and sorry. i cant explain it clearly. english is not my language

Comment: What do you mean with "search is not working properly"? The search finds incorrect values? It finds nothing? It finds the lady in the neighbor? It triggers an error? Something else?

Comment: yes it gives incorrect values. but before i added an expandable row its working perfectly,. it gives the desired output. but after i added expandable row. it gives wrong output. i searched for a value that are not on the html table, and it gives me the last row. which is not supposed to be

Comment: @Teemu sir i added jsfiddle code for clarification of my question. kindly check sir. its not giving the correct result thank you. https://jsfiddle.net/q17cz0o1/